# How to interrupt the execution of a Kotlin coroutine

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine, coroutinescope

I have an API request and I should open new activity or show an error depends on the response.

```
CoroutineScope(IO).launch {
    val result = joinGameWithFriendRequest(inputSessionId)
    if (result.error == "Session id not found") {
        showToast("Session id not found")
        this.cancel() // How to stop here?
    }
    if (this.isActive)
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            val intent = Intent(this@PlayWithFriend, PlayField::class.java)
                    startActivity(intent) //todo start new Activity in a func
        }
}
```

I found a solution using `cancel()` and `.isActive` but it looks bad and if you have multiple consecutive checks, the code will be terrible. Is there some nice way to interrupt the coroutine like "return" in functions?

Comment: you have to throw an exception. In your case it could be `throw IllegalStateException()`

Comment: Do you mean to wrap ```CoroutineScope(IO).launch``` in ```try```?

Comment: no `try/catch` is needed. Replace `this.cancel()` by `throw Exception()`. It just cancel the coroutine, the app wont crash.

Comment: Also, using `CoroutineScope(IO)` is a bad practice, it breaks structured concurrency, which is especially relevant on Android.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CoroutineScope.ensureActive()` function inside a coroutine to check if it's active:

```
scope.launch {
    ...
    ensureActive()
    ...
}
```

If `scope` is canceled the code after `ensureActive()` won't be executed.

---

According to your code, instead of cancelling the coroutine you can just return from the coroutine if some condition is `true`:

```
scope.launch {
    val result = joinGameWithFriendRequest(inputSessionId)
    if (result.error == "Session id not found") {
        showToast("Session id not found")
        return@launch
    }

    // the next code won't be executed if result.error == "Session id not found"
    withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            val intent = Intent(this@PlayWithFriend, PlayField::class.java)
                    startActivity(intent) //todo start new Activity in a func
    }
        
}
```

Comment: If I am not mistaken, `ensureActive()` throws `CancellationException` if the job has been cancelled, no?

Comment: @MehranB yes, it throws `CancellationException` which is preventing the code after  `ensureActive()` function from execution.

Comment: So if you don't use that and just try to run the rest of your code on a cancelled coroutine, you will get a different exception. (not sure what kind). So I believe the point of not wanting to run some code if the job is canceled is to do it silently without crashing anything. and try catch would make the code even uglier which is not what OP wants. so is there a way to do it silently ?

Comment: you don't need try-catch here, CancellationException will be consumed silently, and nothing will crash.

Answer (score 0):

You should `throw CancellationException()` in order to cancel coroutine from inside coroutine.